number of cycles in directed graphs with minimum in- or out-degree
If $G$ is a directed graph with $n$ nodes, and minimum out-degree $k$ and minimum in-degree $h$, are there any known results on how many disjoint cycles exist in $G$, and how many nodes are involved in those cycles?

The following might be useful in the undirected case: https://users.monash.edu/~gfarr/research/slides/Harvey-cycle_minor_talk.pdf. It would help if I knew the exact type of result you're searching for. To the best of my knowledge, there isn't much work done on the directed case, but you might find something in the references.

Noga Alon's 1995 paper "Disjoint Directed Cycles" has some related results
